# Determining handedness of elliptical phase-plane trajectories.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Use matrix methods to find the general solution of the equations
>   $$\dot x=3x+2y,\space \dot y=-5x-3y$$ Sketch the phase-plane
>   trajectories in the vicinity of the origin.

I wrote the equations as
$\mathbf {\dot X}=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 2\\-5 &-3\end{pmatrix}\mathbf X$
where
$\mathbf X=\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}$.
I eventually get
$$\mathbf X= A\begin{pmatrix} -2\\3+i \end{pmatrix}e^{-it}+B\begin{pmatrix} -2\\3-i \end{pmatrix}e^{it}$$
As the eigenvalues here
($i, -i$)
are purely imaginary with have ellipses centred at
$(0,0)$. My question is:

> How do we determine the handedness of the ellipses (and also if
>   possible details of them such as major/minor axis, but I'm not sure
>   this is needed)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The unit tangent vector of the trajetory:

$$\mathbf{T}(x,y)=\frac{(3x+2y,-5x-3y)}{\sqrt{34x^2+42xy+13y^2}}$$

Refering to the sketch of the vector field $\mathbf{T}(x,y)$ below, it's **clockwise**.

[image]